# Why is my onupgradeneeded callback never called when connecting to indexedDB?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I'm trying to get some data stored locally using IndexedDB. Below I'm I have a simple example with which I'm trying to get the onupgradeneeded event to fire

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

      var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB 
                    ||window.mozIndexedDB||window.msIndexedDB;

      var request = indexedDB.open("mydb",2),    

      customerData=[
        {ssn:"444-44-4444",name:"Bill",age:35,email:"bill@company.com"},      
        {ssn:"555-55-5555",name:"Donna",age:32,email:"donna@home.org"}
      ];

      request.onerror = function(event){
         alert("ERROR") ;
      };
      request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
         alert("UPGRADE NEEDED") ;
         var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("customers",{keyPath:"ssn"});
         objectStore.createIndex("name","name",{unique:false});
         objectStore.createIndex("email","email",{unique:true});

         for(var i in customerData){
            objectStore.add(customerData[i]);
         }
      } ;
      request.onsuccess = function(e) {
         alert("SUCCESS") ;
      } ;
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I tried to change the version number but whatever I try onupgradeneeded is never called/fired. Any suggestions why ?

cheers
Luca

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested this in FF 10 and it worked for me. (Until the code tried to use the undefined "db" variable".)

What browser are you using? The upgradeneeded event is only raised in FF 10. Chrome 16 still uses the old draft where you have to check the db.version property and call db.setVersion if it's not what you want.

If you are using FF10, are you sure that "mydb" isn't already created?

Also, be sure that you're testing this through a real web server. FF won't let you use indexedDB with local HTML files. If that's happening, you should see an error like "The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code" in your console.

Comment: check, I upgraded from 6.x to 10 and it is working fine now!
I've tested this stuff before on chrome 17, which doesn't work (also safari/opera do not work)
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define the db variable

I have the same problem... this is the code from MDN, and they didn't explain how to update the DB version without the setVersion() function

Comment: I think they explained that with "indexedDB.open("mydb",2)" you can define your DB version. If that version doesn't match the DB version "onupgradeneeded" is called. That is what I red in their documentation, and sounds very logic, except that it doesn't work :)

Comment: I assume that you obtain the db via: var db = event.target.result ; But because the onupgradeneeded is never called you will not get an error

Comment: if you will ever manage to solve this out, it will be very helpful if you would post it here...