# IndexedDB onupgradeneeded not firing on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, indexeddb, shim

I've read [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092762/indexeddb-onupgradeneeded-never-called) about this kind of problem, so I am aware of the purpose of `onupgradeneeded`, when it should be called and of the browser compatibility problems.

I am developing a web app that should support Chrome on Desktop and Safari on iOS. I am using the IndexedDB in Chrome, but implemented with the [IndexedDBShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) to fall back to WebSQL when I'm using mobile Safari.

The system all works fine in Chrome. In mobile Safari, the first time I load the page with no cached data, it will fail to create the database because `onupgradeneeded` **is not** called. However: if I reload the page, the second time it loads `onupgradeneeded` **is** called. From there, the shim works fine.

At the moment my fix is to show a warning asking the user to refresh the page - it then works.

What can I do that's better?

Comment: Code? Note the event is named `upgradeneeded`. The callback is named `onupgradeneeded`.

Comment: Thanks. Having got this problem I'm keeping it simple and using the code from the [Mozilla Dev pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB). When I have that working I'll put it in my production stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed this problem with the indexedDBShim. If you wait a few milliseconds it works correctly so maybe you can delay your code?

I know this isn't a perfect answer but this is the error which is happening:

```
"could not prepare statement (1 no such table: dbVersions)"
```

Somehow this error is hidden (a bug in the shim), as one of the maintainers I might look into it when I have time :).

This error occurs because this code is called a bit to soon (somewhere around line 1570):

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM dbVersions where name = ?", [name], function(tx, data){
```

This table doesn't exists yet because this code isn't executed yet (around line 1494):

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbVersions (name VARCHAR(255), version INT);", [], function(){
```

In short, there isn't much you can do about it because it is a bug in the shim, delaying the code is I think the only way to fix it on your side. Another possibility is fixing the shim, but that will take some more time I think.

Comment: Great eye! Are you an IDB dev too? We'd love to have you on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/indexeddb-users - the four top SO IDB devs are on there.

Comment: That's the fix, thank you! I'd tried doing a scripted refresh when the error happened which didn't fix it, but as the user doing a refresh action did I should have realised it was a race condition sort of thing. Thank you very much!